# What is _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE?

Tags: linux, gcc

Using the [nm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm) command in Linux to see the symbols in my program, I see a symbol by the name `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` as shown below. Can somebody elaborate what is `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` used for?

```
0000000000614018 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

Comment: From a link-only answer: https://www.bottomupcs.com/ch09s03.html has a chapter about the Global Offset Table and what it's for / how it's used (with an IA-64 Itanium example, lol).

Answer (score 21):

`_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` is used to locate the real addresses of globals (functions, variables etc) for [PIC (Position-Independent Code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Technical_details), its commonly referred to as the GOT.