# How do I provide or remove the dependency on _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_?

Tags: linker, operating-system, rust

I'm working on an OS in Rust, and I am encountering the following error when I try to link:

> undefined reference to '_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'

This is caused by, as best as I can tell, any Rust function that invokes another. I also have `#[no_std]` on. My linker script doesn't include such a reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`, should it?

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x0010000;
SECTIONS
{

   .text phys : AT(phys) {
   code = .;
   *(.text)
   *(.rodata)
   . = ALIGN(4096);
}
.data : AT(phys + (data - code)) {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
}
.bss : AT(phys + (bss - code)) {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
}
end = .;
}
```

I build with

```
>nasm -f aout -o start.o start.asm
>rustc -O --target i686-unknown-linux-gnu --crate-type lib -o  main.o --emit obj main.rs
>ld -melf_i386 -Tlink.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o
main.0.rs:(.text.main+0xb): undefined reference to '_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
>nm main.o         
         U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000 T main
00000000 T memcmp
...
```

How do I include this symbol? Is there a way to remove my dependency on it? The full code with Makefiles is here if anyone wants to try building it: https://github.com/ragingSloth/rustboot

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar. You should include a link to the [Rust issue you opened](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20379), which was then closed.

Comment: I hadn't seen the last post about relocation models haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these two comments in the Rust issue you opened:

> If you don't want the pic or dynamic-no-pic relocation models then you should ask for the static model.

And

> the relocation model can be controlled via the `-C relocation-model=...` argument

And checking to see [what the global offset table is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9685699/155423) anyway, I think you want to update your compiler command to be:

```
rustc -O --target i686-unknown-linux-gnu --crate-type lib -o  main.o --emit obj -C relocation-model=static main.rs
```

Comment: thanks for all the help the past few weeks. that totally did it.