# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I installed gcc 5.3.0 on my mac pro, and i want to compile a c program by using

```
gcc main.c -o matrix -mcmodel=medium -lm
```

however I received this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_", referenced from:
      _stressXXSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressYYSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressXYSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressYZSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressZZSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressXZSX in ccxZn6ac.o
      _stressXXN in ccxZn6ac.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: erro：ld return 1.
```

`_stressXXSX` is a sub function defined before `main()`. This program is ok when it was compiled  on the old computer with ubuntu system.

Thank your for all your suggestion and help!

Comment: Post your code. Take a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685699/what-is-global-offset-table)

Comment: Why do you use `-mcmodel=medium` when building? Have you tried building without it?

Comment: `-mcmodel=medium` doesn't seem to be the default option. Try: `-mcmodel=small`. You should use the same model throughout, and ensure that the OS supports the memory model. Note that this still leaves you with a potentially *huge* 2GiB program, and support for 64-bit data. I myself would leave the `-mcmodel` alone.

Comment: [Is it your case?](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63893)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for your answer. I used the -momodel=medium because there are some big arrays  in my C program, and the default -mcmodel=small, only setting -mcmodel=medium that can compile successful under my old computer with ubuntu system. I tried again just now by setting -mcmodel=small or removing -mcmodel=medium and received the fault below:

Comment: @JoachimPileborginal section layout:
    __TEXT/__text addr=0x10000081F, size=0x0000334F, fileOffset=0x0000081F, type=1
    __TEXT/__stubs addr=0x100003B6E, size=0x00000042, fileOffset=0x00003B6E, type=28
    __TEXT/__stub_helper addr=0x100003BB0, size=0x0000007E, fileOffset=0x00003BB0, type=32
 

ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (5544417526 max is +/-4GB): from _main (0x10000157F) to _AMatrix (0x24A7953E0) in '_main' from /var/folders/r1/79lkfnh96tg3smy56327qhm40000gn/T//cchoF5uJ.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: 错误：ld 返回 1

Comment: Big arrays are a sign of bad design, in my opinion. If you have large initialized global (or local `static`) arrays that will lead to your executable program being unreasonable large. A perhaps better solution might be to dynamically allocate at the start of the program instead, then you don't have to worry about large executables, long compilation times, long load times, or "hacks" like changing the memory model.

Comment: Also, what if you don't actually *use* all the space in the large array, then you waste memory. Better find out the exact size needed at run-time and allocate just the exact amount needed. And if it's a sparse array, there are data structures (and libraries implementing these data structures) that are better suited than a large (and mostly unpopulated) array.

Comment: And finally, maybe you should ask a new question on how to make a better solution for the *actual* problem you have, instead of asking us to solve your solution to an unknown problem? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).