# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: mac gcc

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I installed gcc 5.3.0 on my mac pro, and i want to compile a c program by using

```
gcc main.c -o matrix -mcmodel=medium -lm
```

however I received this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 

"_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_", referenced from: 
_stressXXSX in ccxZn6ac.o 
_stressYYSX in ccxZn6ac.o 
_stressXYSX in ccxZn6ac.o 
_stressYZSX in ccxZn6ac.o 
_stressZZSX in ccxZn6ac.o
 _stressXZSX in ccxZn6ac.o 
_stressXXN in ccxZn6ac.o ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: erro：ld return 1.
```

`_stressXXSX` is a sub function defined before main(). This program is ok when it was compiled on the old computer with ubuntu system.

Thank your for all your suggestion and help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You already helped [into this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277919/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-gcc#comment62087253_37277919).... Why post a new identical one?..